# Coding a hidden message in image

Tags: javascript

I want to code a hidden message in image using js, but don`t know how this works. I have been searching for some algorithm but dont found one. Can some one explain how to encode message in image using js?

Comment: What you want to do is called steganography and isnt a trivial task and explaining how to do it would be too long for the Q&A format of SO. For the most part SO is here to help fix code you already have not teach a whole process. Though you would need to learn how to draw / manipulate images in the canvas, then learn about steganography methods then try to apply those methods in some js way. You would probably need to use some third party libraries to help with some of those tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this library https://www.peter-eigenschink.at/projects/steganographyjs/

It will allow you to hide text into images

**EDIT** - Adding the encoding code from the link

```
Cover.prototype.encode = function(message, image, options) {
  // Handle image url
  if(image.length) {
    image = util.loadImg(image);
  } else if(image.src) {
    image = util.loadImg(image.src);
  } else if(!(image instanceof HTMLImageElement)) {
    throw new Error('IllegalInput: The input image is neither an URL string nor an image.');
  }

  options = options || {};
  var config = this.config;

  var t = options.t || config.t,
    threshold = options.threshold || config.threshold,
    codeUnitSize = options.codeUnitSize || config.codeUnitSize,
    prime = util.findNextPrime(Math.pow(2,t)),
    args = options.args || config.args,
    messageDelimiter = options.messageDelimiter || config.messageDelimiter;

  if(!t || t < 1 || t > 7) throw new Error('IllegalOptions: Parameter t = " + t + " is not valid: 0 < t < 8');

  var shadowCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    shadowCtx = shadowCanvas.getContext('2d');

  shadowCanvas.style.display = 'none';
  shadowCanvas.width = options.width || image.width;
  shadowCanvas.height = options.height || image.height;
  if(options.height && options.width) {
    shadowCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, options.width, options.height );
  } else {
    shadowCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  }

  var imageData = shadowCtx.getImageData(0, 0, shadowCanvas.width, shadowCanvas.height),
    data = imageData.data;

  // bundlesPerChar ... Count of full t-bit-sized bundles per Character
  // overlapping ... Count of bits of the currently handled character which are not handled during each run
  // dec ... UTF-16 Unicode of the i-th character of the message
  // curOverlapping ... The count of the bits of the previous character not handled in the previous run
  // mask ... The raw initial bitmask, will be changed every run and if bits are overlapping
  var bundlesPerChar = codeUnitSize/t >> 0,
    overlapping = codeUnitSize%t,
    modMessage = [],
    decM, oldDec, oldMask, left, right,
    dec, curOverlapping, mask;

  var i, j;
  for(i=0; i<=message.length; i+=1) {
    dec = message.charCodeAt(i) || 0;
    curOverlapping = (overlapping*i)%t;
    if(curOverlapping > 0 && oldDec) {
      // Mask for the new character, shifted with the count of overlapping bits
      mask = Math.pow(2,t-curOverlapping) - 1;
      // Mask for the old character, i.e. the t-curOverlapping bits on the right
      // of that character
      oldMask = Math.pow(2, codeUnitSize) * (1 - Math.pow(2, -curOverlapping));
      left = (dec & mask) << curOverlapping;
      right = (oldDec & oldMask) >> (codeUnitSize - curOverlapping);
      modMessage.push(left+right);

      if(i<message.length) {
        mask = Math.pow(2,2*t-curOverlapping) * (1 - Math.pow(2, -t));
        for(j=1; j<bundlesPerChar; j+=1) {
          decM = dec & mask;
          modMessage.push(decM >> (((j-1)*t)+(t-curOverlapping)));
          mask <<= t;
        }
        if((overlapping*(i+1))%t === 0) {
          mask = Math.pow(2, codeUnitSize) * (1 - Math.pow(2,-t));
          decM = dec & mask;
          modMessage.push(decM >> (codeUnitSize-t));
        }
        else if(((((overlapping*(i+1))%t) + (t-curOverlapping)) <= t)) {
          decM = dec & mask;
          modMessage.push(decM >> (((bundlesPerChar-1)*t)+(t-curOverlapping)));
        }
      }
    }
    else if(i<message.length) {
      mask = Math.pow(2,t) - 1;
      for(j=0; j<bundlesPerChar; j+=1) {
        decM = dec & mask;
        modMessage.push(decM >> (j*t));
        mask <<= t;
      }
    }
    oldDec = dec;
  }

  // Write Data
  var offset, index, subOffset, delimiter = messageDelimiter(modMessage,threshold),
    q, qS;
  for(offset = 0; (offset+threshold)*4 <= data.length && (offset+threshold) <= modMessage.length; offset += threshold) {
    qS=[];
    for(i=0; i<threshold && i+offset < modMessage.length; i+=1) {
      q = 0;
      for(j=offset; j<threshold+offset && j<modMessage.length; j+=1)
        q+=modMessage[j]*Math.pow(args(i),j-offset);
      qS[i] = (255-prime+1)+(q%prime);
    }
    for(i=offset*4; i<(offset+qS.length)*4 && i<data.length; i+=4)
      data[i+3] = qS[(i/4)%threshold];

    subOffset = qS.length;
  }
  // Write message-delimiter
  for(index = (offset+subOffset); index-(offset+subOffset)<delimiter.length && (offset+delimiter.length)*4<data.length; index+=1)
    data[(index*4)+3]=delimiter[index-(offset+subOffset)];
  // Clear remaining data
  for(i=((index+1)*4)+3; i<data.length; i+=4) data[i] = 255;

  imageData.data = data;
  shadowCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

  return shadowCanvas.toDataURL();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any other way without using this library, but writing the code by yourself?

Comment: sure, but it's not really my recommendation. Check out https://github.com/petereigenschink/steganography.js/blob/master/src/encode.js , you copy paste code or just use it for inspiration

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on SO as they dont teach anything not to mention the links could sometime later become dead and make the post useless. If you want to suggest libraries like this then also include a demonstration/explanation of the library within the answer itself